# How to read and understand this kind of code

Tags: c#, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I am reading code that is very strange to me.

How do I read and understand theese code numbers followed by `/u`

```
internal void method_29(int num)
{
    uint num2 = 1u << num;
    this.\u200D\u206B\u202D\u200C\u206E\u202D\u200F\u202E\u200C\u200F\u206C\u206A\u202D\u200B\u202B\u206B\u206E\u200C\u206D\u200D\u206E\u206D\u206C\u200F\u200D\u202E\u206F\u206E\u206F\u202C\u202A\u206D\u206F\u202D\u200E\u202C\u200C\u200B\u206E\u206D\u202E_11.method_34(num2);
    this.\u200D\u206B\u202D\u200C\u206E\u202D\u200F\u202E\u200C\u200F\u206C\u206A\u202D\u200B\u202B\u206B\u206E\u200C\u206D\u200D\u206E\u206D\u206C\u200F\u200D\u202E\u206F\u206E\u206F\u202C\u202A\u206D\u206F\u202D\u200E\u202C\u200C\u200B\u206E\u206D\u202E_17.method_34(num2);
    this.int_6 = num2 - 1u;
}

Class12.property_32 = Operator.Login(Class12.property_24.property_35.get_Username(), Class12.property_24.property_35.get_Password());
Hashtable arg_32_0 = Class12.property_32.get_Payrates();
DateTime arg_3D_0 = Class12.property_32.get_ServerTime();
Class12.property_29 = Class12.property_32.GetNotifications(true);
Class12.property_30 = Class12.property_29.Count;
Class12.property_29.AddRange(Class12.property_32.GetNotifications(false));
Class12.property_28 = Class12.property_29.Count - Class12.property_30;
Class12.property_29.Sort();
Class12.property_29.Reverse();
```

Comment: It's probably decompiled obfuscated code.  You're not _supposed_ to understand it.  It's using non-printable unicode characters in member names.

Comment: They're just unicode characters.

Answer (score 2):

The \u refers to Unicode escape sequences. All Unicode characters from specific groups (Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, Nl, Mn, Mc, Nd, Pc, Cf - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664670(VS.71).aspx) are allowed, even if your editor doesn't play nice with them.